# Separable Algebra

Tags: vector-spaces, field-theory, homological-algebra, extension-field, tensor-products

The definition of a separable algebra from the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_algebra) page is

> An algebra $A$ over the field $k$ is separable if for every field
>   extension $L/k$ the algebra $A\otimes L/k$ is semisimple

Taking $A$ to be a module over a field, i.e. a vector space, and the fact that you can always view the field extension $L/k$ as a vector space (e.g. $L=\mathbb{C}$ and $k=\mathbb{R}$) we get that $A\otimes L/k$ is also a vector space.  Further, we know that every vector space is semi simple.  So my question is, what is an example of an algebra over a field that is not separable according to this definition?

Comment: A classical example of inseparable $k$-algebra is A=$k[X]/(X^2)$.

Comment: @GreginGre Here you are using that any separable algebra is semisimple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Notions of semisimplicity**

In different contexts there are different notions of semisimplicity. I think, that is where your confusion was coming from:

- We call a **vector space** semisimple if it is a direct sum of simple vector spaces.
  A simple vector space $V$ is a vector space whose only subspaces are $(0_V)$ and $V$.
  Now, this is a fairly useless definition. As every vector space has a basis (in the infinite-dimensional case evoke AoC), every vector space is semisimple (as you observed).
- More generally, we call an **$A$-module** over a $k$-algebra $A$ semisimple if it is a direct sum of simple $A$-modules. A simple $A$-module $M$ is one that has only $(0_M)$ and $M$ as submodules.
  (A $k$-vector space is equivalently a $k$-module over the $k$-algebra $k$. Hence, this definition of semisimplicity is indeed a generalization of the first.)
- As a special case we have the notion of a semisimple **$k$-algebra**: One that is semisimple as a left module over itself. Before you ask, yes, one could replace "left module" by "right module" here. But that these definitions are equivalent is apparently a non-trivial result.

Let us apply these notions to your question.
Let $A$ be an algebra over a field $k$ and $L/k$ a field extension. Consider the $L$-algebra $A \otimes_k L$. Of course it is semisimple as a vector space (see above). However, it might not be semisimple as an algebra.

**2. Constructing a non-separable algebra**

Let me give you an example of a non-separable algebra.
Every separable algebra over a field is semisimple (just choose $k=L$, and use the identification $A \otimes_k k \cong A$). Hence, it suffices to look for a non-semisimple algebra. There are quite a few of them.

For a non-standard example consider the Taft Hopf algebra. Let $N\neq 1$ be a positive integer. Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero such that it has a $N$-th primitive root of unity $\zeta$ (for example, $\mathbb C=k$).
Consider the algebra $H$ over $k$ generated by two elements $g$ and $x$ subject to the relations $x^N=0$, $g^N=1$ and $xg=\zeta gx$. It is $N^2$-dimensional with a basis $g^ix^j$ for $0\leq i,j \leq N-1$.

A well known theorem by Larson and Radford from 1988 states that a finite-dimensional $k$-Hopf algebra over a field $k$ of characteristic zero is semisimple (as an algebra) if and only if $S^2=id$ for its antipode $S$.

It turns out that $H$ can be made into a Hopf algebra with the following antipode: $S_H: H \rightarrow H; g \mapsto g^{-1}, x \mapsto -xg^{-1}.$ However: $${S_H}^2(x)=S_H(-xg^{-1})=-S_H(g^{-1})S_H(x)=gxg^{-1}.$$ Here we have used that the antipode is a linear map and an antialgebra homomorphism.
Because $N\neq 1$ we have just shown that ${S_H}^2\neq id_H$. Hence, the algebra $H$ is not semisimple, and therefore not separable either.

**3. On a side note**

By the way, various notions of semisimplicity are unified in category theory.
In an abelian category there is the concept of simple objects and semisimple objects. There is an [nLab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semisimple+object) on these notions.